# How to import external module (async.js) in javascript main file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, module, async.js

So at work we bought a theme that I have to customize and use it for an internal project. They use pug to generate the final files from some templates. In the .pug templates I can insert, of course, some external javascript files.

An empty js example for a file from them looks like this:

```
(function(window, document, $) {
  'use strict';
   $(window).on('load', function () {

   })
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

(jQuery and bootstrap are automatically included in the templates). 
I sucessfully created my javascript files and used them to work on the project using only pure js and some jQuery (however I kind of missed angularjs, but I wasn't able to use .pug and angular in the same time).

I came to the point where I had to make some multiple GET request to a server and I need them to be asynchronous. In my previous projects I successfully used the async module and I wanted to use that here too. Surprise, surprise, I can not import the module.

I tried with a simple line like `import * as async from '../libs/async/async.js';` but if I want to use a simple async.series, it says: `Uncaught TypeError: async.series is not a function`. I tried in every way possible. The errors were varying from the one above to `"Unrecognized token *"`. And yes, I declared the .js file as `type="module"`.

I tried to simulate the problem in by myself and I created the following files structure (it resembles the one in the theme).

```
  .
    ├── assets
    │   └── js
    │       ├── dashboards
    │       │   └── dash.js
    │       └── libs
    │           └── async.js
    └── src
        └── index.html
```

In the .html file, I only include jQuery and the dash.js file. The dash.js file contains the following code:

```
'use strict';
import * as async from '../libs/async.js';

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        function init() {
            console.log("Hello there!");

            async.series([
                function(callback) { console.log(5); callback(); },
                function(callback) { console.log(6); callback(); }
            ]);
        }

        init();
    });
```

But...errors again.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: async is not defined
    at init (dash.js:8)
```

How on earth can I import the async module (or any other module) and use it correctly?

UPDATE:
In the .html file, If I include the line

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.6.1/async.js"></script>
```

it seems it works, but I really want to know if this can be done without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .pug file, changing the order of the .js files helped. I put async.js

```
 script(src=assets_path + '/js/libs/async.min.js', type='text/javascript')
```

as the first line for the custom js files and it worked. No other imports were needed.